Разница begin и cbegin
Можно ли считать cbegin синтаксическим сахаром?
vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it < a.end(); it++) {
  *it = 5;
}

В данном случае даже без cbegin невозможно изменить элементы, зачем он тогда?

for (auto it{a.begin()}; it < a.end(); it++) Ну а синтаксическим сахаром их считать нельзя, так как они не никак не дополняют синстаксис.

Начиная с с++11 уже практически никогда не указывают типы явно в подобных циклах. Да и циклы используют диапазонные типа for (auto& e: a).

В вашем коде вы сперва получаете НЕконстантный итератор a.begin(), но потом преобразовываете его в константный vector<int>::const_iterator, еестественно изменить нельзя )
